# 20 seconts difference betwen ntp-synced servers

Tags: centos, ntp

I've got several CentOS 6 servers, synced to pool.ntp.org time-servers.
But sometimes time on them is out of sync, which make difference for 20-30 seconds, which causes errors in my app.

What can be the cause of this, and where should I look for it?

Config

```
tinker panic 1000 allan 1500 dispersion 15 step 0.128 stepout 900
statsdir /var/log/ntpstats/
leapfile /etc/ntp.leapseconds
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift

statistics loopstats peerstats clockstats
filegen loopstats file loopstats type day enable
filegen peerstats file peerstats type day enable
filegen clockstats file clockstats type day enable

disable monitor

server 0.pool.ntp.org iburst minpoll 6 maxpoll 10
restrict 0.pool.ntp.org nomodify notrap noquery
server 1.pool.ntp.org iburst minpoll 6 maxpoll 10
restrict 1.pool.ntp.org nomodify notrap noquery
server 2.pool.ntp.org iburst minpoll 6 maxpoll 10
restrict 2.pool.ntp.org nomodify notrap noquery
server 3.pool.ntp.org iburst minpoll 6 maxpoll 10
restrict 3.pool.ntp.org nomodify notrap noquery

restrict default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery
restrict 127.0.0.1 nomodify
restrict -6 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery
restrict -6 ::1 nomodify


server  127.127.1.0 # local clock
fudge   127.127.1.0 stratum 10
```

srv1

```
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 server01.coloce .STEP.          16 u  11d 1024    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
+mt4.raqxs.net   193.190.230.66   2 u  510 1024  377    6.367    5.984   7.433
+16-164-ftth.ons 193.79.237.14    2 u  217 1024  375   11.339   -0.028   4.564
*services.freshd 213.136.0.252    2 u  419 1024  377    6.735    2.048   4.321
 LOCAL(0)        .LOCL.          10 l    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
```

srv2

```
    remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
+ntp2.edutel.nl  80.94.65.10      2 u  527 1024  377   11.924    1.469   0.753
-95.211.224.12   193.67.79.202    2 u  364 1024  377   12.989    4.930   0.628
+app.kingsquare. 193.79.237.14    2 u  339 1024  377    5.485    0.493   0.591
*ntp.bserved.nl  193.67.79.202    2 u  206 1024  377    7.007    0.539   0.420
 LOCAL(0)        .LOCL.          10 l    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
```

Comment: Show the configuration of each server please? Also show the output from `ntpq -p` on each server.

Comment: You may have better luck on serverfault.com.

Comment: @EtanReisner added config and `ntpq -p` output in question

Comment: The configuration is identical on all the servers? What is the time on each of those two servers? Does disabling the local clock help any?

Comment: @EtanReisner For now, time is synced, I haven't tried to disable local clock. I'll try it now, and give a feedback. Thank you.

Comment: You might also want to add a fifth peer. I believe the common wisdom is that you want at least five for reliable and robust time resolution (but I'm far from an expert on this).

Comment: I was getting similar issue. Running this solved the issue. Put this code in a script (set_date.sh) and run it via cron if reqd. sudo date -s "$(wget -qSO- --max-redirect=0 google.com 2>&1 | grep Date: | cut -d' ' -f5-8)Z"